# Can Random Forest predict/assign obs. to each class with the same weight as the weight in training sample?

Tags: random-forest

Assume that I have 5 classes and they are imbalanced. 
Those classes have weights like
10%, 20%, 40%, 20%, 10%

I have more than 100 predictors to do the prediction.

Can I somehow ask random forest to predict a new sample based on those predictors in the new sample but produce also 10% of class 1, 20% of class 2, 40% of class 3, 20% of class 4, and 10% of class 5?

It means that I hope the prediction of class 1 account for 10% in my sample, etc.

Usually there will only be 5% or less of the predictions to be for class 1.

Also, if I try to separate my original sample into training sample and prediction sample so that I can see the accuracy rate of my out-of-sample prediction. The out-of-sample accuracy rate is only about 80%. The in-sample accuracy rate is about 99% or 100%.

At first, I thought it has some unbalanced data problem so I tried to use class weight and stratified sampling. None of them seem to work.

Does this mean that my predictors are not good enough? Or is there any other way to solve it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to do or why you would want to do it.  Are you saying you want 10% of the predictions to be for class 1, etc.?   If so, the answer is "no."  Think about what you would want to predict if all your predictors were irrelevant; if the loss of mis-predicting doesn't depend on what the true class is or what the prediction is, the best prediction will be "class 3" all the time, which is right 40% of the time.  Think about why you would want to predict otherwise...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I mean I want 10% of the prediction to be for class 1. I am not sure if I get you correctly. My predictors are relevant. Do you mean that maybe my predictors are not enough? Otherwise, I could get what I want? I have modified the question. Hope I make it clearer now.

Comment: Even if your predictors are relevant, wanting 10% of them to be for class 1 (in all likelihood) isn't a good goal to have.  For an event that has a 10% probability of occurring, you need a lot of evidence to think it is more likely to occur than an event that has a 40% probability of occurring *and* more likely than an event that has a 20% probability of occurring *and* a different event that has a 10% probability of occurring, and if you don't have that much evidence, then you'd be making a mistake to choose the unlikely event over the more likely events.  Think about why you want to do this.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for an RF-autoencoder.  (https://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/AAAI/AAAI18/paper/viewFile/16868/16612)